# Format for student "résumé" for capstone projects?

Tags: cv, undergraduate, projects

This coming semester, I am "managing" (teaching?) the capstone projects for eight undergraduate students. We are going to start from scratch in terms of ideas for projects, but one aspect I want to include is the students' backgrounds and interests.

I am thinking that these should be presented in a short-form résumé.

Because the projects will eventually consist of teams of 2 to 4 students, having this background information will help make compatible groups.

Does anyone have experience doing this?

I'm thinking that it should just be a [functional résumé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9#Functional_r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9):

> A functional résumé lists work experience and skills sorted by skill area or job function.
>
> The functional résumé is used to focus on skills that are specific to the type of position being sought. This format directly emphasizes specific professional capabilities and utilizes experience summaries as its primary means of communicating professional competency.

Is this a good idea?

Does anyone have any pointers to templates used specifically for assessable work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to go with a functional résumé.

The benefits were:

- The students could tailor the academic course list to those relevant to their projects.
- The students could emphasize some of their background interests that were also relevant.

The downsides were:

- Some students didn't "get" the idea of a functional résumé and needed several iterations to achieve one.
- Some students had much more relevant experience and more relevant courses than others, which reflected badly on the students with little relevant experience or coursework.

Though both of these downsides led to teachable things, which is part of the aim of the capstone project.

Because I wanted to show all of the résumés on a projection screen, I chose the following non-standard format to show them  in one page.

[image: Functional résumé template]